# Securing SprintBoot Web App using Azure AD

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

Getting this error:
unable to acquire on-behalf-of token for client f93*****-3***-4***-a***

Please help!!
I am able to do firstime login and try changing password.After that clicking Login gets this error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the admin has enabled user consent.

[image]

If you have already done that, try updating to SpringBoot 2.3.3. There was an issue in earlier version that could cause this to happen.